# Function filter breaking tag archive menus

Tags: functions, tags, archives

Ok, I'm setting up a site with a some CPT's.  When creating posts under said CPT's, we added tags.  When viewing the posts results after searching, tags were displayed, but upon clicking the archive page indicted that no results were available.

So, I added the code below to my functions.

```
function myTagFilter($query) {
$post_type = $_GET['type'];
if (is_tag()){
    if (!$post_type) {
        $post_type = 'any';
    }
    $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
}
return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts','myTagFilter');
```

Now, posts from the CPT's display in the tags archive, but the menu is broken.  Here's a link if you want to test it out.

http://mt-spacehosting.com/fisheries/?s=framework+50

So, my question is, why would the menu break because of this?

Comment: Which menu is broken?

Comment: The topnav and the sidebar custom menu are both not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_tag()` is true for the entire tag archive page and for any queries that run on it. You need to restrict that code to only run for the main query on that page and that hte query is a tag query and not some other kind of query, like a menu query. You do that by checking the actual query object being used.

```
   function myTagFilter($query) {
      $post_type = $_GET['type'];
      if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tag()){
        if (!$post_type) {
            $post_type = 'any';
        }
        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
      }
      return $query;
    };
    add_filter('pre_get_posts','myTagFilter');
```

`is_tag()`, `is_single()`, and other conditionals like that are *functions* that check the `global` `$wp_query` object. You have to be careful not to use them to check things that are not that `global` object.